# Porting some arduino code in stm32: problem with word data type

Tags: types, arduino, byte, stm32, cpu-word

I'm porting some arduino library code to stm32. 
I'm having issues with the word data type and complier give me " the expected expression before 'word' " error.
this is the code:

```
uint8_t au8Buffer[MAX_BUFFER];
uint16_t *au16regs;
....
if(i%2)
{
    au16regs[i/2]= word(au8Buffer[i+u8byte],  lowByte(au16regs[i/2]));
}
```

Of course on the Arduino library the compiler don't give error.
Any suggestion?

I tried to replace word with unsigned short or uint16_t but the error persist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Martin put it, the code is trying to combine two 8-bit pieces into a 16-bit piece, but your compiler is not interpreting it that way.  You can define functions as Martin suggests or preprocess into something the compiler will understand via:

```
#define word(argA,argB) (((argA) << 8) | (argB) )
#define lowByte(argA) ((argA) & 0xFF)
```

Depending on what else you have going, using (and managing) preprocessor macros or additional functions may be just as troublesome as changing code.
So if that's the only place you need it, you could replace

au16regs[i/2]= word(au8Buffer[i+u8byte], lowByte(au16regs[i/2]));

With

au16regs[i/2]= (au8Buffer[i+u8byte] << 8) | (au16regs[i/2] & 0xFF);

Comment: I also should define other funcions like that: highByte (that I think is similiar to lowByte), bitRead and bitWrite functions from Arduino. Do you know how to do that?

Comment: You could try #define highByte(argA) ((argA) >> (8*(sizeof(argA)-1)))

Comment: #define bitRead(argA,argB) (((argA) & (1 << (argB))) != 0)

Comment: #define bitWrite(argA, argB, argC) ((argC) ? ((argA) |= (1 << (argB))) : ((argA) &= ~(1 << (argB))))

Answer (score 0):

according to Arduino documentation, the type "word" is equivalent to stm32 "uint16_t". So, you need to pack 2 bytes into one 16bit word.
You can do the following:

```
uint16_t word = (higherByte << 8) + lowerbyte;
```

So you could implement the "mWord". Also you need to implement "LowByte" to get your example working. Here is a posible implementation:

```
uint16_t mWORD(uint8_t H, uint8_t L)
{
    return (((uint16_t)higherByte) << 8) + lowerbyte;
}

uint8_t lowByte(uint16_t w)
{
    return (w & 0xFF);
}
```